# Facebook Connect Mobile Web - page requested not found

Tags: php, facebook

Im creating a mobile website and trying to implement facebook connect. I am using the PHP SDK

I have following code:

```
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                'auth_token' => $session['auth_token'],
                'next' => 'http://www.site.com/fbconnect',
                'cancel' => 'http://www.site.com/fbconnect',
                'canvas' => 0,
                                    'fbconnect' => 1,
                                    'req_perms' => 'publish_stream'));
```

I sign in, but I never get redirected back to my app. I stay on m.facebook.com w/ a msg
The page you requested was not found.

Is there something im missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your site details under the "website" section of your app need to point to the same directory as you call from, that is the most common issue for failure to callback to your site.  Assuming the "next" is the URL you wish the user to return to of course.

Comment: Yea they are identical. I also have the cancel pointing to same url and if i click cancel that part works =(